# How do I add a timer in libgdx java?

Tags: java, android, timer, libgdx, collision

I am trying to add a timer for power ups in my game. What I am trying to do is change a parameter (like jump height for example) after the player has collided with the power up box but it should only apply for 4 seconds. I have already written the collision coding and have added a random element to choose which power up is activated. I have also added a power up that will not use the timer (adding 1 to the score).

Searching google I found code using various methods like Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() and Timer.schedule but I can't seem to get them to work, maybe I am coding them incorrectly. I've been trying to use code like this but when using System.out.println(timeSinceCollision), I keep getting a constant value every time and it doesn't seem to be increasing.

```
float timeSinceCollision = 0;
timeSinceCollision += delta;
if(timeSinceCollision < 4f) {
 // the action
} else {
 // reset

}
```

Comment: I would recommend using the CountDownTimer class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you can use the CountDownTimer class.

```
new CountDownTimer(4000, 4000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    public void onFinish() {
       isPoweredUp = false;
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I tried using it but eclipse tells me 'CountDownTimer cannot be resolved to a type'. There are 5 quick fixes available including change to 'Counter' (org.w3c.dom.css), change to 'Counter' (sun.management.counter), create class CountDownTimer, create interface CountDownTimer and fix project setup.

Comment: It's a built in Android class-- I don't know why it's not showing... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Well since I am using eclipse, I am making the desktop and android version simultaneously. What would the desktop version be?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating timeSinceCollision every time with value of 0 thats why it never increase.

Take a look at my function. the If condition will be true every 4 seconds.

```
    final float TIME_SINCE_COLLISION = 4;
    float timeSinceCollision = 0;

    public void update(float delta) {

        timeSinceCollision += delta;
        if (timeSinceCollision >= TIME_SINCE_COLLISION) {
            timeSinceCollision -= TIME_SINCE_COLLISION;
            // Do something after 4 seconds.
            Gdx.app.log("Do something", "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to do. I want to make a change in jump height for example for 4 seconds after the player hits the power box. With this code, it changes every 4 seconds regardless of whether the player collides with the power box or not. Think of it like the star power up in super mario.